# Convert the following system to a first order system:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Really having a hard time with this.....Convert the following system to a first order system:

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} -3\frac{dy}{dt}+x=\sin(t)\\ \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} -t\frac{dx}{dt} - ye^t =t^2$$

Comment: You should format your question with LaTex; take a look at how I edited your question so you know for future reference.

Comment: Can you think of a way to write it as a system for $(x,\dot x,y,\dot y)$?

Comment: Thank you graydad for doing that!

Comment: @Bobby Just a friendly reminder in case you don’t know how the site works: after you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "upvote" and/or "accept" the answer by clicking the up arrow and the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question and will encourage others to answer your other questions. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to convert an (uncoupled) second order scalar equation into a first order system? For example, can you convert $x''+x'+x=f(t)$ into a first order system?

The key there is to let $u=x$, $v=x'$ so that $u'=v$ and $v'=u'=x''$ and then $$x''=-x'+x+f(t)$$ becomes $v'=-v+u+f(t)$ and so on.

So in this coupled situation, just use that same technique twice, once for each ODE:

Let $u=x$, $v=x'$ and $p=y$, $q=y'$. Then $u'=v$, $v'=u''=x''$ and $p'=q$, $q'=p''=y''$. Then your first ODE says 
$$x''=3y'-x+\sin t\implies v'=3q-u+\sin t,$$ while from the second ODE says $$y''=tx'+e^ty+t^2\implies q'=tv+e^t p+t^2.$$

Gathering things into matrix form, $$\begin{bmatrix} u\\v\\p\\q\end{bmatrix}'=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\-1 & 0 & 0 & 3\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\0 & t & e^t & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\\p\\q\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\\sin t\\0\\t^2\end{bmatrix}.$$